# How to replace column value with another rows column value based on condition using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a better way of doing the below manipulation?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id": ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    "date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-11", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-06", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-20"],
    "type": ["start", "start", "closing", "start", "start", "closing", "closing"],
})

for id in df['id'].unique():
    closing_date = df.loc[(df['id'] == id) & (df['type'] == 'closing'), 'date'].min()
    df.loc[(df['id'] == id) & (df['date'] > closing_date), 'date'] = closing_date
```

Comment: please add an example of the dataframe so people can try it out

Comment: if you expect several closing per id, please update your example to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` to get the closing date per group, then replace the values that are greater with boolean indexing:

```
closing = (df['date'].where(df['type'].eq('closing'))
           .groupby(df['id']).transform('last')
          )

df.loc[df['date'].gt(closing), 'date'] = closing
```

output:

```
  id        date     type
0  a  2020-01-01    start
1  a  2020-01-10    start
2  a  2020-01-10  closing
3  b  2020-01-06    start
4  b  2020-02-01    start
5  b  2020-02-20    start
6  b  2020-02-20  closing
```

If you have several "closing" per id and want to ensure getting the most recent one:

```
closing = (df['date'].sort_values()
           .where(df['type'].eq('closing'))
           .groupby(df['id']).transform('last')
          )

df.loc[df['date'].gt(closing), 'date'] = closing
```

Comment: probably sort by `date` then `transform('first')`, or sort descending `transform('last')`.

Comment: @Quang do you think it's necessary? Assuming there is a single closing per id that shouldn't matter, no?

Comment: op's code is expecting multiple `closing` per id. probably he should go back to whoever produced the initial data and tell them to clean it up before they pass it on. but that's not our problem... lol

Comment: The author used `.min()` in his code, so I think it should be possible

Comment: Then OP should clarify how to handle it with a meaningful example

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to find a nice middle ground between the fully procedural (but fairly readable) approach you started with, and the more fully pandas (but less readable, imho) approaches in the other answers, by popping out your logic as a function operating on a sub-dataframe with just the "id" in question, and then simply applying:

```py
def make_start_precede_close(subdf):
    closing_date = subdf.loc[subdf['type'] == 'closing', 'date'].min()
    subdf.loc[subdf['date'] > closing_date, 'date'] = closing_date
    return subdf

df.groupby("id").apply(make_start_precede_close)
```

Ultimately, you'll have to make a decision about tradeoffs between testability, reusability, readability and performance. Pure-pandas is likely to win at performance (though not necessarily), but popping out an explicit function wins in the other categories, from my experience.

Comment: modifying `subdf` within the function might trigger `SettingWithCopyWarning` and might not work. `groupby().apply` is certainly slow(er) when there are a lot of `id` values.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid doing things row by row (or id by id). First I groupby the variable `id` and find the minimum date. Then I merge this data with the original dataframe to create a `closing_date` column, which has a value for every row. Now we only need to take the minimum from the original column `date` and `closing_date`. Finally, we remove the `closing_date` column.

```
closing_date = df[df['type'] == 'closing'].groupby('id').date.min()
df['closing_date'] = df.merge(closing_date, on='id').date_y

df['date'] = df[['date', 'closing_date']].min(axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns='closing_date')
```

Output:

```
  id        date     type
0  a  2020-01-01    start
1  a  2020-01-10    start
2  a  2020-01-10  closing
3  b  2020-01-06    start
4  b  2020-02-01    start
5  b  2020-02-20    start
6  b  2020-02-20  closing
```